# Why is Finestra VDM acting up?

Tags: windows-vista, desktop, virtual-desktop

I installed Finestra VDM yesterday, and it keeps acting up. What I mean by that is that it keeps switching desktops unwillingly as soon as I touch the mouse! I have disabled hotkeyes from the taskbar menu but it continues to act by its own will.

All I see is this screen coming up, indicating that the desktop is being switched.

[image: desktop switch]

**Q:** What's going on? How do I stop it? I mean except by uninstalling it?

**Update:**

Okay, I understand now that it only does this when I move the mouse cursor to either top, bottom, left, right side of the screen, or one of the corners (I think makes it switch diagonally like from desktop 1 to 4).

By the way, I tried dragging a file from one virtual desktop to another, and before even I had the chance to drop it at the second desktop I got a crash message.

[image: NET Framework crash]

This is very nice! Thank you Finestra! I'm sure this "feature" is usefull... at times... when it actually works. But I want to get rid of it anyway. It prevents me from using my monitor as I normally would (I can't go to the edges of the screen), and by that also prevents me from using my computer.

Comment: I don't see the options dialog. Despite clicking on it, it just won't show up.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I managed to get to the options dialog window. Here's a short how-to for future reference.

1. Open the Options dialog window. To get it open you need to right-click on the Finestra VDM icon in the system tray, and from the pop-up menu you need to click on "Options". But the trick is that you have to click on the far left edge of it where you see that little gear icon. It won't open if you click on the middle of the "Options" entry or on the far right edge of it. Also, try pressing the mouse key a little harder (and longer) and then let go, just to make sure it really recognizes the mouse button. You will have to play with it a little until you get it to open the Options window.
   [image: options]
2. Once you get into the Options dialog window it's pretty easy from there. You need to go to Interface tab, and then un-tick the "Mouse edge switching" option.
   [image: Finestra options dialog]
3. Click OK to save changes. Finestra VDM will have to restart now. You will probably see a warning message telling you that some other software is using the hotkey it needs. You will see this message, even if you know for sure that no other software is using the same hotkey. Don't worry, this is normal in Finestra VDM. Whenever you restart it, like when you save settings, it will give you a finger like this. The only software using this hotkey on my computer is Finestra itself, and apparently it's not aware of it.
   [image: hot hot hot... key]